# Java рассылка сообщений Telegram bot как сделать? Как лучше?

Tags: java, sql, telegram-bot, telegram, рассылка

Возник вопрос по поводу рассылки сообщения в Telegram bot. Chat id храниться в БД. Как сделать рассылку сообщений есть вариант с :

1. https://api.telegram.org/botTOKEN/sendMessage?chat_id=CHAT_ID&text=TEXT

Как-то по другому?

Если по больше вариантов нету то как сделать так чтобы бот рассылал сам после того как я нажму кнопку ОТРАВИТЬ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Массив сделайте с нужными id и отправляйте сообщения в цикле for или foreach через определенный временной интервал, скажем 100мс, ну или более 1-5с, чтобы сервера телеграмма не посчитали это за спам.